# Is the Symbol a case object?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

```
{ sealed trait Sealed; case object Foo extends Sealed; case class Bar(s: String) extends Sealed; trait Baz extends Sealed }
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val List(bar, baz, foo) = symbolOf[Sealed].asClass.knownDirectSubclasses.toList
```

I've tried `.asClass.primaryConstructor.isStatic`, but that doesn't work if the sealed trait is defined as dependent type.

Comment: Can't check now, but doesn't isModule do the trick? It won't differentiate between object and case object though.

Comment: @Jasper-M nope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Symbol#isModuleClass` looks like it can determine if the symbol is an `object`, and `foo.asClass.isClass` can determine whether it has the case modifier. Note that `asClass` will throw an exception if you use it on other type of symbol, though (method, term, etc).

**Object test**:

```
scala> bar.isModuleClass // case class
res28: Boolean = false

scala> baz.isModuleClass // trait
res29: Boolean = false

scala> foo.isModuleClass // case object
res30: Boolean = true
```

For other types:

```
scala> val a = ""
a: String = ""

scala> symbolOf[a.type].isModuleClass
res34: Boolean = false

case class A(value: String) ; object A { def default = A("") }

scala> symbolOf[A].isModuleClass
res35: Boolean = false

scala> symbolOf[A.type].isModuleClass
res36: Boolean = true
```

Based on the API documentation and [SI-6012](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6012) it *seems* like `isModule` should also work, but it only returns true for the `companionSymbol.`

**Case test**:

```
scala> bar.asClass.isCaseClass // case class
res44: Boolean = true

scala> baz.asClass.isCaseClass // trait
res45: Boolean = false

scala> foo.asClass.isCaseClass // case object
res46: Boolean = true
```

For other types (same definitions as the examples above):

```
scala> symbolOf[a.type].asClass.isCaseClass // plain singleton object
res47: Boolean = false

scala> symbolOf[A].asClass.isCaseClass // case class
res48: Boolean = true

scala> symbolOf[A.type].asClass.isCaseClass // non-case object
res49: Boolean = false
```

**Putting it together**:

```
def isCaseObject(symbol: Symbol): Boolean =
  symbol.isModuleClass && symbol.asClass.isCaseClass

scala> isCaseObject(bar)
res50: Boolean = false

scala> isCaseObject(baz)
res51: Boolean = false

scala> isCaseObject(foo)
res52: Boolean = true

scala> isCaseObject(symbolOf[a.type])
res53: Boolean = false

scala> isCaseObject(symbolOf[A])
res54: Boolean = false

scala> isCaseObject(symbolOf[A.type])
res55: Boolean = false
```